# AngleSharp Parsing

Tags: c#, html-parsing, anglesharp

Can't find many examples of using AngleSharp for parsing when you don't have a class name or id to use.

HTML

```
<span><a href="google.com" title="Google"><span class="icon icon_none"></span></a></span>
<span><a href="bing.com" title="Bing"><span class="icon icon_none"></span></a></span>
<span><a href="yahoo.com" title="Yahoo"><span class="icon icon_none"></span></a></span>
```

I want to find the href from any `<a>` tags that have a title = Bing

In Python BeautifulSoup I would use

```
item_needed = a_row.find('a', {'title': 'Bing'})
```

and then grab the href attribute

or jQuery

```
a[title='Bing']
```

But, I'm stuck using AngleSharp
eg. following example 
https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Examples#getting-certain-elements

c# AngleSharp

```
var parser = new AngleSharp.Parser.Html.HtmlParser();
var document = parser.Parse(@"<span><a href=""google.com"" title=""Google""><span class=""icon icon_none""></span></a></span>< span >< a href = ""bing.com"" title = ""Bing"" >< span class=""icon icon_none""></span></a></span><span><a href = ""yahoo.com"" title=""Yahoo""><span class=""icon icon_none""></span></a></span>");

//Do something with LINQ
var blueListItemsLinq = document.All.Where(m => m.LocalName == "a" && //stuck);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like there was problem in your HTML markup that cause AngleSharp failed to find the target element i.e the spaces around angle-brackets :

```
< span >< a href = ""bing.com"" title = ""Bing"" >< span class=""icon icon_none"">
```

Having the HTML fixed, both LINQ and CSS selector successfully select the target link :

```
var parser = new AngleSharp.Parser.Html.HtmlParser();
var document = parser.ParseDocument(@"<span><a href=""google.com"" title=""Google""><span class=""icon icon_none""></span></a></span><span><a href = ""bing.com"" title = ""Bing""><span class=""icon icon_none""></span></a></span><span><a href = ""yahoo.com"" title=""Yahoo""><span class=""icon icon_none""></span></a></span>");

//LINQ example
var blueListItemsLinq = document.All
                                .Where(m => m.LocalName == "a" && 
                                            m.GetAttribute("title") == "Bing"
                                       );

//LINQ equivalent CSS selector example
var blueListItemsCSS = document.QuerySelectorAll("a[title='Bing']");

//print href attributes value to console
foreach (var item in blueListItemsCSS)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.GetAttribute("href"));
}
```